# Shading a honeycomb board

Tags: combinatorics

The following figure shows a honeycomb  board that is bounded by an equilateral triangle.

[image: honeycomb board]

The $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ row contains $9 - (i - 1)$ cells for each integer $1 \leq i \leq 9$. A game is played on the board. Every time a token is placed on the board,
all the cells on the same row and on the same diagonal as it are shaded. (An instance of the shading from a turn is shown.) Determine the minimal number of turns required to shade the figure.

**Comments**

By induction, for every positive integer $n$, the maximum number of turns to shade a similar honeycomb figure with either $2n - 1$ or with $2n$ cells along an edge is $n$. As there are 9 cells along the base of the given figure, and as $9 = 2(5) - 1$, the maximum number of turns required to shade the given figure is 5.

**Requests**

What is the minimum number of turns to shade the board? Is there a convenient rule for computing the minimum number of turns needed on a similar board with $n$ cells along the bottom row?

Comment: It would be immensely useful to just include the rendered TeX images as PNGs or the like.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki   I do not know how to include images on this web site.

Comment: When you are editing your post there is an icon that looks like a box with some mountains and a sun for add image.  You have enough rep to do so.  You can add jpeg, png, and some other formats

Comment: @Ross Millikan  I see the icon.  It does not allow me to upload a `pdf` file.

Comment: When I click on it I get a box that says drag and drop here.  clicking on the box opens a browse window to find the file on your hard drive.  I have used .jpg  and .png files that way.

Comment: I have replaced the TeX code with the image. (I did not think the TikZ source code was important, and if anyone wants to see it anyway, it's still in the edit history.)

Comment: @Misha Lavrov  Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by maximum and minimum number of turns is unclear. Why is $n$ the maximum number of turns rather than the minimum number?

Comment: @Aravind we know how to shade a $2n-1$ or $2n$ size board in $n$ turns, and we would like to know if it's possible to do in $n-1$.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov: I understand the comment from Aravind. Why does the OP think $n$ is a maximum? It looks more like a possible minimum.

Comment: @Jens  No, the argument provided in the post (that could be shown easily by induction) shows that at most $n$ tokens would need to be placed to shade the board.  Perhaps less than $n$ would be required.  In fact, in the case that $n=4$, only 3 tokens are required to shade the whole board.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire I don't see that solution. Is it for the 7-board or the eight-board or both?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen  It is for the honeycomb board with 7 cells along each edge.  Here is where to put the three tokens:  first row, third cell; third row last cell; fifth row, first cell.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(n)$ be the minimal number of tokens required to cover a triangle of side length $n$.

**Theorem.** $f(n)=\lceil\frac n2\rceil$.

*Proof.*
This is certainly true for $n=1$ and $n=2$.
Also, by placing a token on a vertex of the triangle, we reduce the side length by $2$ and so obtain
$$f(n)\le 1+f(n-2) $$
for $n>2$. Thus by induction, 
$ f(n)\le \lceil\frac n2\rceil$ for all $n$.

Assume place $m$ tokens on an $n$-triangle, where $m<\lceil \frac n2\rceil$, i.e., $2m<n$.
Each token by itself covers exactly $2n-1$ of the $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ places (as this is true at a vertex, and moving by one step changes one line by $+1$, one by $-1$, and one not at all).
Hence, ignoring any overlaps for different tokens,  $m$ tokens cover $(2n-1)m$ places.

Question: How much overlap is between two tokens?

There are three ways to designate an "up" direction and view one of the edges of the triangle board as the "bottom" edge.

- If the two tokens are on different "heights" (for all three interpretations of "up"), one of the tokens is the "lower" token for at least two choices of "up". For both these choices, the "horizontal" row of this "lower" token intersects the two "skew" rows of the "upper" token in a place that is not the lower token itself. Thus we count at least $4$ places of intersection.
- If the tokens are on the same "height" for one of the three interpretations of "up", the overlap is a full row of at least two places plus at least one additional intersection of the skew directions "above" that row. This immediately gives us at least four places of intersection, except when the common row has length $2$, i.e., both tokens are next to a vertex; but  in this special case, one directly verifies (using $n>2$) that there are four intersections as well.

Thus for each pair of tokens, we have to subtract (at least) $4$ from the total count of covered places. Hence $m$ tokens cover at most
$$m\cdot(2n-1)-4{m\choose 2} =2\cdot m\cdot(n+\tfrac12-m)$$
places. The function $x\mapsto x\cdot(a-x)$ is strictly increasing for $x\le \frac a2$. Hence for $m<\frac n2$, the above expression is strictly smaller than 
$$2\cdot \frac n2\cdot\left(n+\tfrac12-\frac n2\right)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}, $$
the total number of places on the board.
In other words, $m<\frac n2$ tokens  cannot cover the full board.
We conclude that  $f(N)\ge \frac N2$, and as $f(n)$ is an integer, we have $f(n)\ge \lceil \frac n2\rceil$, as desired. $\square$

Comment: Apparently, this is wrong. After reading @user74973's description of the size-7 solution, it is clear that triple intersections have to be added back in (full form of inclusion-exclusion principle) ...

Comment: In the placement of the three tokens on a honeycomb board with 7 cells along an edge that I described in another comment, at least one cell would be shaded three times: the third cell in the third row (from the bottom).